# CSS - Multi Line Wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

If you can help i just want to have some guidance with regards to the following problem.[image]

Basically if I have too much text in the description of the image, it pushes the image up. What would be the most attractive way of dealing with such an issue?

Thanks.

I created a basic fiddle - re-size the window to get them inline

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7aLaL0pe/)

```
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future peoples, I decided that a flex solution would really help me here.

I created the following css code:

```
.file-wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}
.file-image {
    padding: 30px;
}

.file-box {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    flex-basis: 10em;
    margin: 1em;
}

.fileTextWrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
}
.file-text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The HTML is very self explanatory. The wrapper contains all the elements, and then I have divs for the mages and their descriptions. By doing this not only are they responsive but they are aligned in the centre and the text is wrapped nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` for same approach Update below css part

[Update code](https://jsfiddle.net/7aLaL0pe/1/)

```
div.gallery {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    align-items:center;
    padding:10px;
} 

    div.gallery img {
    /* width: 30%; */
    height: auto;
}
```

```css
div.gallery {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-flow:column nowrap;
    align-items:center;
    padding:10px;
}
div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
   /* width: 30%; */
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
          
          
          <div class="responsive">
                <div class="gallery">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/img/zip.svg')}}"/>
                    <div class="desc">Description</div>
                </div>
        </div>
        
                 <div class="responsive">
                <div class="gallery">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/img/zip.svg')}}"/>
                    <div class="desc">Description Description</div>
                </div>
        </div>
        
                 <div class="responsive">
                <div class="gallery">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/img/zip.svg')}}"/>
                    <div class="desc">Description Description Description Description Description Description</div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

This would make all boxes equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.responsive` div, so all div will align from top..
check below snippet

```css
div.gallery {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15.99999%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
          
          
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="{{ asset('/img/zip.svg')}}" />
        <div class="desc">Description</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="{{ asset('/img/zip.svg')}}" />
        <div class="desc">Description Description</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="{{ asset('/img/zip.svg')}}" />
        <div class="desc">Description Description Description Description Description Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your notion on a what an attractive solution means and since it hasn't been proposed already. You could use text-overflow ellipsis.

```
div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You could display the full filename as a tooltip in addition.